# Wav Reader and processor in java and basic wav questions to make sound recognition

Tags: java, audio, fft, frame, wav

I'm  trying to make a music recognition system. I'm afraid I might not be reading the wav samples as I was supposed to, and also, that I might be applying the wrong window sizes to make the FFTs and others.

It would be great if you help me out.

First, I have some questions regarding audio processing in Wavs.

1) Wav has a header right? So will the following code read correctly the wav file?

```
private static byte[] getAudioBytes(String path_to_audio) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException{

    File audio_file = new File(path_to_audio);
    //
    AudioInputStream audio_input_stream = AudioSystem
            .getAudioInputStream(audio_file);
    byte audio[] = new byte[(int) audio_file.length()];
    audio_input_stream.read(audio);

    return audio;

}
```

1.1) If there is a header, how can I read it, and what are their fields? (I'm confused about the different headers that I saw online)

2) Another question, is I guess, the recording of the wav file has a default Frame Size. Am I correct?

2.1) I have to send every frame into FFT. If I use a different frame size to send the samples to the FFT, this will retrieve wrong results, correct?

2.2) If different frame sizes retrieve wrong results, how can I use bigger frames, in order to get better frequency accuracy ? (for example, lets say the original file has 1024 sample frames and I want to use a 4096 sample frame size)

3) It would be good to use both on my sample wav file and in my original file the same bit depth, right?

4) if it's a 16 bit depth I have to use short in java right?

In my code I was reading frames with a 4096 samples in it, without concerning the recording frame size. I saw a few examples of song recognition but they don't explain much of this details, and just said they used 4096 as a frame size for example. I tried to search this kind of info and a found little information, so I'm asking for help here.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wav has a header. Right?

Yes. A good reference on the structure of a wav file at the raw bit-level can be found in [the WAVE format specifications](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html).

> So will the following code read correctly the wav file?

It will correctly read the wav header of supported wav files (be prepared to handle `UnsupportedAudioFileException` for less common extensions), and extract the audio data in raw encoded form (i.e. you still have to decode the raw data yourself to get meaningful samples). Note however that this code allocates more than the required buffer size since `audio_file.length()` includes the header size, whereas the data buffer read does not (i.e. the data buffer is only filled with the encoded samples).

> If there is a header, how can I read it, and what are their fields? (I'm confused about the different headers that I saw online)

The header field indicated in [the WAVE format specifications](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html) are already read by `AudioInputStream` which then assigns the relevant fields (e.g. `encoding`, `channels`, etc.) of an [`AudioFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html). Note that it is not an exact one-to-one mapping since `AudioFormat` is a generic representation that is shared with other audio file types, but it very often all you really need to care about. This `AudioFormat` can be accessed with `audio_input_stream.getFormat()`. If you want to specifically look at the bit structure of the file header (or just want to torture yourself) you could also use a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) directly.

> The recording of the wav file has a default Frame Size. Am I correct?

Not quite. The "Frame" used by `AudioInputStream` in the case of wav files corresponds to a single time instant which includes just as many samples as the number of channels (e.g. a frame would be a single sample for a mono file and 2 samples for a stereo file). The size of such a frame is always implied from various fields (such as number of channels, number of bytes per sample, etc.) in the wav header, and applies to the entire stream. Also, the data is packed as a contiguous block of channel interleaved samples, so there are no additional separations into larger blocks of samples.

> I have to send every frame into FFT. If I use a different frame size to send the samples to the FFT, this will retrieve wrong results, correct?

If you send all channels of a multi-channel (for example stereo) wav file to a single FFT then you are likely to get results that do not correspond to your expectations. However, once you have separated the channels you are free to perform the FFT with any length of your own choosing (and still get reasonable results).

> If different frame sizes retrieve wrong results, how can I use bigger frames, in order to get better frequency accuracy ? (for example, lets say the original file has 1024 sample frames and I want to use a 4096 sample frame size)

Since there really only is one block of data per channel once you have deinterleaved the channels, the only case where you cannot directly use an FFT size of the same size as the available data size is if your original file has fewer samples than the FFT length you wish to use. However, you can still perform the larger size FFT by zero-padding the file samples.

> It would be good to use both on my sample wav file and in my original file the same bit depth, right?

That depends on your specific application requirements. The input file bit depth is often given to you with little you can do about it. You would typically control the output file bit depth. Just keep in mind that truncating your samples to use a smaller bit depth is a lossy operation. It is thus often a good idea to keep as many bits as possible throughout your processing, truncating at the very end. So for example you may choose to same your output with a larger bit depth than your input if that output is an intermediate result in a longer processing chain.

> If it's a 16 bit depth I have to use `short` in java. Right?

Correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave a huge help!